# Forward requests to regional API based on a specific JWT claim

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to forward requests to regional API based on a specific JWT claim?

The platform I'm working on has one API per region, and our customers are required to know it in order to build the base request URL - e.g.: https://{region}.service.com

Unfortunately, the only reliable way to try and figure out which regional api to call automatically from Azure APIM (e.g.: calling a single endpoint at https://api.service.com), in our scenario, would be by analyzing a claim that always comes with the bearer token (which we already do [at the APIM level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).)

Has anybody had the need to do it this way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitaly's answer was the key to figuring this one out. Here is the complete answer, in case anybody is looking for the same thing.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <!-- Extract Token from Authorization header parameter -->
        <set-variable name="token" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization",string.Empty).Split(' ').Last().AsJwt())" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["token"] != null)">
                <set-variable name="api_uri" value="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["token"]).Claims.GetValueOrDefault("api_uri", string.Empty))" />
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Variables["api_uri"] != string.Empty)">
                        <set-backend-service base-url="@((string)context.Variables["api_uri"])" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise />
                </choose>
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 1):

APIM policy expressions along with "choose" policy allow you to create arbitrary processing logic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions.

Access to JWT is available as

```
context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").AsJwt()
```

It returns Jwt object (look for it's properties on the same page above).

All this combined with "set-backend-service" policy should be sufficient to do the job.